# How to query CouchDB for date range and item id?

Tags: couchdb

My couchDB document key is like:

```
["2016-05-01","1"],
["2016-05-02","2"],
["2016-05-03","1"],
["2016-05-04","2"],
["2016-05-04","1"],
["2016-05-05","1"],
["2016-05-05","6"].
```

My question is that, how can I query to this key to get the result between 1-5 date for item id 1.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to reverse the order of the keys and then query the view:

```
http://......../view?startkey=[1,"2016-05-01"]&endkey=[1,"2016-05-05"]
```